# classical decomposition method(without seasonal component)

Tags: time-series, seasonality, decomposition

I understand the following points:

When decomposing, the trend is obtained from the data by a regression line.=> T

A cyclic component containing irregular variations is obtained(series/linear regression data)=> C*I

Smoothing is used to isolate the cyclic component.=>C

Getting an irregular component=(C*I)/C => I

Unclear: how to calculate a typical cyclic component.
Specifically, how to get intervals and observations for the calculation of " typical cyclic component".
In the example, the interval is three, and the observations in each interval are 6.
But, there is no description of how to get these numbers.
To make a prediction for the future I need to get a typical cyclic component

Comment: Perhaps I incorrectly expressed.
In General, I need to calculate the decomposition forecast for the future.
If the data that denoted as "I understand the following points" are known, 
then what further transformations are needed to get the forecast?

Comment: And how to calculate the number of cycles on the chart?
More precisely, how to identify them?